# Bridging Objective-C headers causes Swift compiler errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a bridging header that I use to import a number of Objective-C headers. However, at compile-time, Xcode throws around 80 compiler errors in each of the headers.

They are errors like `expected a type` and `Cannot find interface declaration`. I think Xcode is trying to compile my Obj-C headers as Swift.

Is there a way to fix this? To make them compile in their respective languages, that is. Thanks!

Comment: you should show a screen shot of of what the link to your bridging header looks like in XCode, and post a screenshot of where this error is occurring, there's too much going on here to now what's going on unless you give more detail.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. Regardless, sorry for the lack of context.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` at the top of the bridging header resolved the swift compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, SwiftCompiler error was flagged for a bunch of Objective-C methods.

To resolve this you need to add the framework import statements to the Bridging-Header.h